# How to get the start and end day of every week in a month using strtotime?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I need to grab data weekly from monday to friday and i need to separate it by weeks. Week 1 needs to be the first week of the month (if the 1st is on MON-FRI) but start at the first and go to the end of the week on friday.
For example April week 1 would be Wednesday the 1st to Friday the 3rd all the way to week 5 being  Monday the 27th to Thursday the 30th(last day of the month)
The problem I have is that it gets skewed if the 1st of the month is on a saturday or sunday and the weeks get thrown off.

```
   $week1start = date('m/01/Y',strtotime("this month"));
   $week1end = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("first friday of this month"));
   $week2start = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("first monday of this month"));
   $week2end = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("second friday of this month"));
   $week3start = date('m/d/Y',strtotime(" second monday of this month"));
   $week3end = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("third friday of this month"));
   $week4start = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("third monday of this month"));
   $week4end = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("fourth friday of this month"));
   $week5start = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("fourth monday of this month"));
   $week5end = date('m/30/Y',strtotime("this month"));
```

Comment: if the 1st of the month is on a saturday or sunday then grab the date using `strtotime("next Monday")`

Comment: but then what would everything else be? because it changes every month

Comment: have you try **date("m/d/Y H:i:s", @"123123123" + 6 * 86400)** ??

Comment: **1 day = 86400** with strtotime.

Comment: yes but that doesnt answer my question to the logic of getting certain dates

Comment: do you know **mkdate**????